# Drawable resource not visible while using aar plugin in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, aar, android-unity-plugin

Here is sample dialog I am showing in unity, In that Icon not visible. contain of dilaog are comming from aar. Image at leftside is sample from android app and rightside is from unity.[image]